# App doesn't show up when browsing Android Market via smartphone

Tags: google-play

My Android app doesn't shows up when browsing Android market from a smartphone.  However, when I browse via https://market.android.com from my laptop, it appears.

I double checked my developer console settings and I do not filter out any countries or devices.

I've tested this on various Android devices (LG optimus, galaxy nexus s, etc) from within Canada and the US.

Answer (score 0):

This is a know issue: [source](http://support.google.com/androidmarket/developer/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=known_issues.cs).