# App not visible in mobile google play

Tags: android, google-play

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [App doesn’t show up when browsing Android Market via smartphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557958/app-doesnt-show-up-when-browsing-android-market-via-smartphone)

I have developed an app and uploaded it on android market successfully but when am searching my app using web browser then its visible but while searching with mobile on Google play its not visible.

don't know whats happending..?? Help me..?

Comment: There are few things that might have affected your app visibility. 1) Your device Android version and App minSdk version is not matching. 2) Your Device might have selected not a compatible device while publishing. 3) Region of the device might not have the compatibility.

Comment: what are these few things..?

Comment: Thanks Kumar, i already checked these issue.

Comment: How much time has passed since you uploaded ? It takes quite a few hours these days.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your Manifest lacks:

```
<supports-screens 
    android:xlargeScreens="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in Publishing options.

Log in to Developer Console.
Check whether you checked the checkbox "All Countries" under Publishing options.
And also check whether your app support for all screen layout.

Comment: Thanks Cyber boy, Let me check.!!